# Is there a shortkeys supported audio player on linux?

Tags: linux, audio, music, language

**Background**: I'd like to listen the foreign language material sentence by sentence, so I want a audio player that has shortkeys for play/pause/backward/forward/**repeat**. The repeat function is most important.

**Requirements**: I use Linux. The software can be based on command line, or web browser, or X, etc.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My go to would be mpd with ncmpcpp as the frontend, though many others would probably work.

By default <kbd>r</kbd> toggles repeating.